# loop video and hide controls in firefox HTML

Tags: html

i have this code, works fine on IE, but in the firefox, it shows the controls and dont loop, how can i fixe it?

heres the code:

```
"<embed type='application/x-mplayer2' pluginspage='http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/' name='mediaplayer1' ShowStatusBar='none' EnableContextMenu='false' autostart='true' height='580' width='564' loop='true' repeat='true' src='videos\separador2.wmv' ShowControls=0>
<PARAM name='uiMode' value='invisible'>
<param name='animationatStart' value='true'>
<param name='transparentatStart' value='true'>
<param name='autoStart' value='true'>
<param name='playState' VALUE='true'>
<param name='loop' value='true'>
</OBJECT>"
```

Comment: For starters, your code opens an <embed> tag but closes an </object> tag.

Have you looked at the Error Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters to pass to embedded media players are completely unstandardised, and common media players support difference names and functionalities. You could try setting `playcount` to `0` in addition to `loop`, and setting `controls` to `hidden` in addition to `showcontrols`.

This is just one of many ways in which embedded media players are unreliable. In this decade I would strongly recommend avoiding them. Flash video has much wider deployment and user acceptance, and there's HTML5 `<video>` (not widely-enough supported to use as a sole delivery method yet, but a nice alternative to bolster the Flash, until more browsers implement it).

Comment: thanks for the tip, i will try to convert the video to flash.